# Optimization of SQL query based on attribute (not having specific value) in joined table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

My models structure: Movie `has_many :captions`. Language of the Caption may be “en”, “de”, “fr”...

Problem:
An effective query to select Movies that don’t have Captions with an “en” language.

App that needs above runs on Rails, and for this I’m currently using something like this in Caption model:

```
def self.ids_of_movies_without_caption_in_en
  a = (1..(Movie.last.lp.to_i)).to_a
  b = Caption.in_lang("en").collect {|h| h.movie_id }
  (a - b)
end
```

As you can see, I collect id’s (lp) of all movies and then I remove from that array id’s of those movies where Captions have “en” as a language. The outcome is an array of id’s of Movies I need.

Above works, but as you can imagine it’s quite “heavy”. I believe that there is a better (and maybe trivial) approach to it. However, being “fresh” with SQL, I ask for some guidance in writing an efficient query. This runs on PostgreSQL
Implementation in Rails (5.2) would be an additional bonus!

**This is the situation:** let's say in the database there are 1000 movies, and 4000 captions for those movies. There are of course movies that don't have any captions. Out of those 4000 captions 400 are in "en" language. The query I'm looking for would return 600 movies, where caption in "en" does not exist (including movies with 0 captions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy in SQL.  I'm not quite sure what the tables look like, but something like this:

```
select movie_id
from captions
group by movie_id
having not bool_or(language = 'en');
```

If you want movies with no captions, then use `not exists`:

```
select m.movie_id
from movies m
where not exists (select 1
                  from captions c
                  where c.movie_id = m.movie_id and
                        m.language = 'en'
                 );
```

Comment: nope, `select movie_id from captions group by movie_id having not bool_or(language = 'en');` does not return what is expected. I appreciate your kindness. ... I really hope the problem is not in my definition of the problem ... :)

Comment: @RobertBegier . . . How does it not work?  This seems to be the answer to the question:  "An effective query to select Movies that don’t have Captions with an “en” language.".

Comment: I have extended the initial question with more description, in case I defined my problem not exactly correctly. Query suggested by you returns 20 records instead of expected 600+. Unfortunately I am not able to say what exactly it returns, for my understanding of SQL is not that good.

Comment: @RobertBegier . . . I see.  `not exists` is more appropriate.

Comment: well sir, you are a pro indeed!  I adapted your query to my tables, and it looks like that `select m.lp from movies m where not exists (select 1 from captions c where c.movie_id = m.lp and c.language = 'en' );`. That returns the result only couple of records different from my initial code in rails. I will try to understand the origin of this. Very big thank you!

Comment: Hereby I confirm that query using `not exists` is exactly correct SQL solution to my problem.